# Is it possible to check maximum value of a variable in SPIN/PROMELA

Tags: parallel-processing, multicore, spin, promela, model-checking

In my model checking code, I'm only interested in finding the maximum value of a certain variable. The procedure I employ now is to have an assert statement `assert( var < MAX_VALUE )`, and keep changing the MAX_VALUE in a binary search fashion. However, it would be a lot better, if SPIN actually had a way to just give the maximum possible value of a variable in just one run. I know UPPAAL has a `sup` operator for that. Is there any equivalent in SPIN?

Answer (score 1):

There [does not appear to exist](https://spinroot.com/spin/Man/promela.html#section0) such a `Promela` operator that has a `max` effect (finite domains involved, so equivalent to `sup`).

One possible approach is to record state information while the state-space is being explored, for example via [embedded C code](https://spinroot.com/spin/Man/c_code.html) within the Promela specification. The embedded C code will dump the value of `var` to an external file, whenever `var` changes value, as follows:

```
c_code{
    FILE *fp;
    int max_value;
}
```

together with an [`inline`](https://spinroot.com/spin/Man/inline.html):

```
int var;

inline set_var(value){
    var = value;
    c_code{
        fp = fopen("max_value.txt", "r");
        fscanf(fp, "%d", & max_value);
        fclose(fp);
        if (now.var > max_value){
            fp = fopen("max_value.txt", "w");
            fprintf(fp, max_value);
            fclose(fp);
        }

}
```

In order to find the maximal value, the entire state-space should be enumerated, which depends on what kind of property is being checked, and whether partial-order reduction is applied.

This approach could be improved by more efficient access to the file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I amended the `inline` with a `c_code` to track state globally during model checking.

Comment: I guess coupling this with `assert(var < MAX_INT)`, or an equivalently safe upper bound estimation, should now do the trick. :) +1